# Adder propagate P expression

Tags: digital-logic, adder

When dealing with carry-look-ahead adders, the following expressions are commonly used:
$$P=A \oplus B$$
or
$$P = A + B$$
I understand that using the second expression takes less gates for calculating the propagate signal. When computing the final sum
$$S=A \oplus B \oplus C$$
where C is the carry from the previous stage, the sum expression contains the first expression. Doesn't this mean that using the first expression saves gates without causing extra delay (because that expression has to be calculated anyway for calculating the final sum)?

Therefore, why is the second operation sometimes used as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing NAND and NOR functions is cheaper than computing XOR and XNOR.  While the best ways of computing `X XOR Y` and `X XNOR Y` are slightly cheaper than anything that could by synthesized out of NAND and NOR gates, it may be cheaper still to synthesize them out of other signals like `X OR Y` or `X AND Y` if those have also been computed for other reasons.  If one computes `X OR Y` for `P`, and `X AND Y` for `G`, then the combined cost of computing `P==X OR Y`, `G=X AND Y`, and `S1=P AND NOT G` will be cheaper than synthesizing `P=X XOR Y`, `G=X and Y`, and `S1=P`.

Note that I've slightly over-simplified things here; computing `X AND Y` in isolation would require computing `X NAND Y` and then inverting the result, but if complemented forms of X and Y are available it could instead be evaluated as `X' NOR Y'` for the same cost as a NAND.  Any real evaluation of the relative costs of different ways of writing out logic should take such issues into account.  Further, running wires for a significant distance on a chip can be expensive; if X and Y are needed in two places that are some distance apart, evaluating `X nand Y` in both places may be cheaper than evaluating it in one place and running a wire to feed that result to the other.

Comment: Would you say that the Wikipedia page on this topic is too reductionist? It talks about the OR vs XOR at "Carry lookahead method". It says: "For binary arithmetic, OR is faster than XOR and takes fewer transistors to implement. However, for a multiple-level carry lookahead adder, it is simpler to use XOR".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder

Comment: @gilianzz: Which approach ends up being more efficient may depend upon the technology used to construct a circuit and the relative costs of gates versus routing, the availability of both true and complemented versions of inputs, etc.